# Can some one help me add a CSS code that will move the text on a portfolio box to the bottom of the box and display it permanently

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm trying to move the text to the bottom of this image ( it only shows the text when your hover)

Currently, it looks like this
On my website

https://wtxnews.co.uk/

[The portfolio widget on WTXNews.co.uk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYoYj.jpg)

And ideally, I want it to look like - so the text you see can be at the bottom of that picture and always show

At the moment I am using two blog posts and moving the text upwards to do this, like this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9KLo.jpg)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I dont have any more code

Comment: You're using Elementor, you'll have to find settings change the layout, or use another widget or another method to display the posts as per your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

are the two options
You can do both with section and column editing
If image widget -> text widget -> post info widget
In the second option, simply make a bottom margin of -130 in the widget of the image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqBnC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjZso.png)

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful. But is there no way to ensure it doesn't have a massive layout shift?